# How to show two addresses for a contact on joomla contact page?

Tags: contact

Is it possible to modify the joomla contacts to have two addresses and diplay them both? working with joomla 3 and the com_contacts page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, one approach to this is to modify the HTML of the com_contacts module html in your template.